# Small Wesnoth tournament format suggestions

Tags: battle-for-wesnoth

I'm thinking of having a small Wesnoth tournament with some friends (maybe 8 or 9 ish people) and was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for the format?

Everyone in free-for-all isn't very exciting, and a single team match isn't really a great show of skill.

What do you think? Perhaps a series of 3-player matches with a knock out system?

Any and all suggestions welcome and considered!

Comment: Wesnoth tourney!  Sounds like good times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know many rounds you can fit in your schedule but you might be interested to look at a [Swiss tournament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_tournament) structure. That way you all can play 3-4 matches 1 vs 1 and get a nice ranking out of it. If you want you can still add one or two rounds of single elimination matches for the top 2 or 4 players...